# How can we pass header information to a JsonDataSource?

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports, datasource

We are using REST endpoint as datasource for jasper reports, but everywhere using REST point its mandatory to create an adapter with rest url and header info and use that as datasource.

We don't want to use adapter, instead we want to use directly the constructor

> `public JsonDataSource(String location, String selectExpression) throws JRException`

as a dataset expression so we formed expression as follow.

```
new  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource("http://vagrant.ptcnet.ptc.com:2280/Windchill/trustedAuth/servlet/odata/D...","value")
```

However this particular endpoint expects some header information from requestor `("Accept", "application/json")` else it throws bad exception as error

Is there any way we can pass header info here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the constructor where you pass a `InputStream`

> [`public JsonDataSource​(java.io.InputStream jsonStream,java.lang.String selectExpression)`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JsonDataSource.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String))

The easiest way to provide the input stream is probably to create a method within your java project that execute the request and returns the result in for example a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)

If you need to do it directly within the report (jrxml) you need to do it in 1 expression (jrxml do not support multi-line code). In this case you could the apache [`HttpClients`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients.html) that already is included as dependency of the jasper report project.

It could be something like this

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource(
    org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault().execute(
       org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder.
       get().
       setUri("http://vagrant.ptcnet.ptc.com:2280/Windchill/trustedAuth/servlet/odata/D...").
       setHeader("Accept", "application/json").
       build()
       )
    .getEntity()
    .getContent()
   ,""
)
```

The `getContent()` will return the `InputStream` and jasper reports will close this stream when it is done. However both the client and the execute response are theoretically [`Closable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html?is-external=true) which means that normally you should call `close()` to free up resource, hence I'm not sure that it is enough to close only the InputStream, you may risk leaking of resource. This is why I initially suggested to create a method within the/a java project where this can be handled appropriately.